# SQLite date function doesn't appear in SELECT results

Tags: sqlite, sorting, date

I've just started using SQLite, instead of SQL Server, and it doesn't seem to want to do `ORDER BY, MAX() or MIN()` on dates.

The `Survey_Date` column is a text field, so ordering it sorts it from January to December, instead of by the year. If I include `date(Survey_Date)` in my `SELECT` statement, it will `sort` the data by year -- but I can't override the `DESC` sort, and it doesn't actually display the date.

```
SELECT Survey_Date FROM Surveys WHERE Loc_ID = 32 ORDER BY Survey_Date;
```

yields results like:

> ```
> 01/10/2009
> 01/20/2013
> 02/05/2010
> ...
> ```

```
SELECT date(Survey_Date), Survey_Date FROM Surveys WHERE Loc_ID = 32 ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

yields results like:

> ```
> |01/20/2013
> |02/05/2010
> |01/10/2009
> ...
> ```

It's clearly sorting on the date correctly now, but it doesn't display the formatted date, and doesn't recognize the `ASC` command.

Can anyone explain what it's doing?

Comment: Are you sure that `date` does not just return `NULL` because it cannot parse your date format? Is it really "clearly sorting correctly"?

Comment: I fixed the issue (for what I need) by adding a Survey_Date LIKE '%2015' to the select and sorting the text Survey_Date field. As long as all the dates were from the same year, the text sort worked fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already explained at least million times over this site, **SQLite does not have date/timestamp type**.

So if you want to sort by date, you must store them in format that sorts correctly either numerically, or lexicographically (asciibetically/unicodebetically).

The [recommended format](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime) is [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), that is yyyy-mm-dd (yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS if you want a time too). This is what SQLite has some [utility functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to work with, too.

Other possible formats are numeric, either number of seconds since some specific point, e.g. [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) or number of days, e.g. [(Modified) Julian day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day).

> ```
> 01/10/2009
> 01/20/2013
> 02/05/2010
> ```

They are strings, so this is correctly sorted.

> `SELECT date(Survey_Date), Survey_Date FROM Surveys WHERE Loc_ID = 32 ORDER BY 1 ASC;`

1. The [`date`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) function expects [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. It does not understand what you are giving it and returns NULL. Fully expected.
2. Sorting by all `NULL` values effectively does nothing. The rows came out sorted by accident.

Comment: @Thilo, hm, checking documentation, it, at least in the current version, actually should. Updating.

Comment: Or to sum up, garbage in, garbage out!

Comment: Thanks, @Jan Hudec. I was relying on the documentation, which said it would convert text in a recognizable format. Of course, it didn't say what "recognizable" was. ISO-8601. Got it.

Comment: @JenniferDunne, well, "recognizable" depends on the database. SQLite only recognizes ISO-8601 (subset of it; ISO-8601 has variant without separators and with 2-digit year and such and SQLite only accepts the basic variant), and says so in [its official documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).